# Не могу получить атрибут при парсинге jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Добрый день.

Пишу парсинг сайта на jsoup, в результате получаю искомую строку вида

```
<p class="name"><a href="/level/1/book/22446/sr/1/" class="js-serp-metrika" data-url="/book/22446" data-id="22446" data-type="book">Название</a> <span class="year">2015</span></p>
```

Застрял на том, что не получается вытащить значение атрибутов data-type и data-url.  Пробовал по всякому, выводится пустая строка. Сайт jsoup зачитал до дыр.

Пробовал так

```
Elements named = doc.select("p.name");

  for (Element el : named)
    System.out.println(el.select("data-url").attr("data-url"));
```

и так

```
System.out.println(el.select("data-url"));
```

и так

```
System.out.println(el.attr("data-url"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У элемента `p` нет этих атрибутов. Эти атрибуты есть у элемента `a`. Вот такой код даст атрибут

```
Elements named = doc.select("p.name > a");
System.out.println(named.first().attr("data-id"));
```

Comment: А как теперь вытягивать содержание класса year?  Он находится в элементе р.  Можно ли как-либо объединять селекторы p.name > a и p.name?

Comment: @Tariel задайте новый вопрос